# How can I see hidden files in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

Some Android apps use my Google Drive account to backup their data. However, I am not able to see any files. I want to see and download a copy of the backup data.

Are these files hidden? How can I view them from a browser?

I want to store it in my computer which is running Linux.

---

I found out that these are hidden files. How can I view them?

[image]

As you can see in the image, below EGW Writings, it says *Hidden app data*. I want to see it and download it. Is there a way?

Comment: Have a look at this https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/19606?hl=en.

Comment: For those looking for a Backup file, it will be displayed under the backup section in the lefthand menu of Google Drive. Usually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like they can't be accessed from anyone but the app itself:

> The user cannot directly access data in the hidden app folders, only the app can access them. This is designed for configuration or other hidden data that the user should not directly manipulate. (The user can choose to delete the data to free up the space used by it.)
>
> The only way the user can get access to it is via some functionality exposed by the specific app.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22844899/1045199

**EDIT** (thanks Ruben)
See Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata

Comment: It's better to quote an authoritative source. In this case https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata

Answer (score -3):

On your laptop when in documents click on View and then tick Hidden items and they should appear. To take them off hidden right click the folder and go to properties and untick hidden

Comment: I don't see any of these links you're referring to. Can you add screen shots?

Comment: The solution that you are mentioning is apparently based on the assumption that Google drive for PC/Mac will download ALL of the data and then the app folder can be manually marked as unhidden. The probability for this assumption is very low as Google has blocked the direct access for data integrity purposes