# How to locate WhatsApp backup file in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, android, whatsapp

I cannot login my 2-step verified Google Account in my Oneplus 3T because of Oneplus restriction in Google services. 
So I am thinking to find the WhatsApp backup file and recover the backup manually in my phone which has a different email address than my previous WhatsApp.

I know WhatsApp FAQ [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20887921/?category=5245251) where is no question about the problem here.

I know the thread [How can I see hidden files in Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73940/how-can-i-see-hidden-files-in-google-drive) but which is not about WhatsApp and the hidden directory of WhatsApp is not given there.

Email sent to WhatsApp support email address because the mono access restore function of WhatsApp is preventing to restore backups from hidden directories in Google Drive in the specific configurations

> Dear Sir/Madam,
>
> You cannot access Gmail account with 2-step protection on Oneplus:
>   https://android.stackexchange.com/a/183863/9897 Your WhatsApp app
>   completely relies on the function, preventing me recovering my
>   WhatsApp account.
>
> Related thread: [How to locate WhatsApp backup file in Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110856/66725)
>
> OS: Android 7.1.1
>   Phone: Oneplus 3T
>
> Best regards,
>
> [Leo]

OS: Android 7.1.1
Phone: Oneplus 3T

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I know it. No solution there to this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see hidden files in Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73940/how-can-i-see-hidden-files-in-google-drive)

Comment: @Rubén Not duplicate, since no WhatsApp Directory location is given there.

Comment: Question on this site are marked as duplicate when the answer is the same, which is happening here: "The user cannot directly access data in the hidden app folders, only the app can access them. "

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to restore Whatsapp backup from Google Drive manually because the related files are on a hidden app folder.

Related Q&A on Android Enthusiasts

[Read Whatsapp Backup from Google Drive](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/138708/71386)

---

From [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79576/88163) to [How can I see hidden files in Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/73940/88163)

> Seems like they can't be accessed from anyone but the app itself:
>
> > The user cannot directly access data in the hidden app folders, only the app can access them. This is designed for configuration or other
> >     hidden data that the user should not directly manipulate. (The user
> >     can choose to delete the data to free up the space used by it.)
> >
> > The only way the user can get access to it is via some functionality exposed by the specific app.
>
> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22844899/1045199
>
> **EDIT** (thanks Ruben) See Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata